# Sending Email is not working in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

Sending Email is not working in server side but working in local system.
I  tried port 25 and 465 instead of 587. But it doesn't work .

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com",ToEmail,"Password reset", message);     
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); 
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "pswd");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Are you sure the server is allowed to access out to that machine and port?

Comment: I faced same issue and changed my password (more secure) and it worked for me

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: why UseDefaultCredentials=true, if you set one explicitly?

Comment: @Shailesh Chaudhary . Thank you so much. I changed my password , Made it strong. Now it works.   Thank you all for the suggestions and answers.